# AWS RDS Mysql community - Spring boot

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

Has anyone connected a spring boot applciation running on local to AWS RDS Mysql community (free tier) version.
I have tried the usual way by specifying:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://<endpoint as shown on the amazon DB details page.amazonaws.com>:3306
    username: <user>
    password: <password>
    initialization-mode: always
```

This throws exception in spring

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I have included the mysql driver in the POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Anyone got any clue??
Oh and yes, I selected the 'allow access to public' on aws for the db instance, also added a security profile selecting http-custom-anywhere

Screenshot for inbound rules aws:
[image]

Outbound Rules:
[image]
Thanks,

Comment: In your RDS instance, there is a security group, can you check the INBOUND and OUTBOUND rules of the group? Can you provide those informations ?

Comment: @Shawrup Like I mentioned in the original post the security was setup to 'from anywhere' I've now edited the post to include a screenshot for your benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outbound rules are wrong.

It should be :

[image]

Comment: did you mean Inbound? Changing only outbound to the above did not work, but changing the Inbound as well to 'All Traffic' then worked and the application was able to connect. I'll probably need to find out what is the exact match, Also, I see i set it up to custom TCP may be it should've been custom HTTP. Anyway, it's worked so I can experiment more with this. Thank you for your answer